# C# My code has a problem taking input and will not start incrementing or decrementing until a button is hit twice nor are my ><= statements working

Tags: c#, user-input, increment, decrement

Here is what is happening.

First issue is:

I need to press a directional button twice to start incrementing and/or decrementing the x and y variables.

If I change directions for an ex.

From Right to Left, the x variable will increment once more before it'll start decrementing.

The Second Issue:

I have time based on current x and y of player.

However when I go above 2000 the time does not change until 2001.

If I go back down to 1999 the time doesn't change until 1998...

This was the same thing even when my code said

`if(y>=0 && y< 2000)`
It was the same issue, I thought taking 2000 and making it 1999 would fix that and it did not.

I do not know what is causing either of these issues and I have tried to figure it out... If anyone knows why it is happening like that, I would love to know.

```cs
int x = 1995;
int y = 0;
int time = 0;

Console.WriteLine("X: 0Y: 0Time: 0");

while(true){
   ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey().Key;
   Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop -1);
   Console.WriteLine($"X: {x,6} Y:{y,6} Time: {time,3}");
   Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft, Console.CursorTop +1);
   //Change Timezones
   if (x >=0 && x< 1999){
      time=0;
   }
   else if (x>=2000 && x< 3999){
      time=1;
   }
   ....
   //Movement   
   if (key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow){
      x=x-1;
   }
   else if (key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow){
      x=x+1;
   }

   ....
}
```

Comment: Please properly format your code. It's confusing to read.

Comment: Doing this on a phone.... And what do you mean?

Comment: Writing code on a phone? That will be difficult, just because you lack the overview. I'll try to fix the formatting.

Comment: You're writing and running the code on your phone???

Comment: The posted code has several syntax errors, and it is completely unclear what it should do. x is never changed.

Comment: Your code appears to assume the x and y integers. Could they in fact be something else, eg. float, or double?

Comment: @PMF Sorry had a typo with x and put a y instead. And what syntax errors?

Comment: @Dr.OgdenWernstrom I will fix that, but yes they are intergers.

Comment: @Enigmativity no I am writing and running it on my computer. I am typing this on my phone.

Comment: "Sorry had a typo" you can avoid typos by creating a copy of your project and minimizing it to become a [mre]. Only post code which you have actually run.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'll take the extra step next and make a copy of it on notepad then transfer the file to my phone. However what I wrote would also still have worked it was just confusing for the read to follow along with what I wrote....

Comment: Sure, there were a few badly written lines that wouldn't compile, sure there's some code missing from the example that means an answerer has to use his imagination a little.  In the end, the question **is answerable**, and people are keen to throw more questions around rather than answer the question and breeding red herrings until we're overrun with fish!

Comment: I don't mean a copy of the .CS file. I mean a copy of the whole solution (including .SLN, .CSPROJ and other files) What's up with the phone? Why is a phone involved?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Because I am using my phone for this website. I am unable to post this using my computer as I have no internet were I live. So I have to access this site on my phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1 "**From Right to Left, the x variable will increment once more before it'll start decrementing.**"

That's because you print out the value of the previous iteration rather than the new value.  Move your `Console.WriteLine` to the end of the script and it'll show you the updated value

Problem 2 "**However when I go above 2000 the time does not change until 2001.**"

This is caused by the same thing as problem 1 most likely.  It could also be caused by the fact you might be changing the value of `x` *after* running the change timezone codeblock.  Be sure the ordering of your logic is correct.

Problem 3 "**If I go back down to 1999 the time doesn't change until 1998**"

There's a gap between the values in your logic.  You have `x < 1999` in your first timezone codeblock, and `x >= 2000` in your second timezone codeblock.  That means if you start at `2003` for example and go down in value, the time will only change when you reach `1998` because of the `x < 1999` part.  There's a value that won't trigger a change when decrementing nor incrementing, `1999`.

Comment: Thank you working me through my issues I was having, even with a load of other errors in the copy I wrote here.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLert, Console.CursorTop, -1);
```

does not compile because it must be `Console.CursorLeft`.

Problem 2:

No overload of `SetCursorPosition()` takes 3 arguments. Maybe you want

```
Console.CursorTop -1
```

Problem 3:

The variables `x`, `y` and `time` are not initialized, so you can't use it in the line

```
Console.WriteLine($"X: {x,6} Y:{y,6} Time: {time,3}");
```

Problem 4:

Comparisons in C# require a variable on both sides in the line

```
else if (x>=2000 && < 3999){
```

try

```
else if (x>=2000 && x<3999){
```

Problem 5:

There's a gap in your definitions:

```
x< 1999 // ... 1997, 1998
x>=2000 // 2000, 2001, ...
```

so you're leaving out 1999

Comment: These are the problems with the compilation, fair things to point out, but won't solve the asker's issues with the expected output.  I suspect he's manually copied the code by typing it into his phone and introduced even more problems than he started with...

Comment: In fairness your Problem 5 is a genuine logic flaw, so that's good :)

Comment: So what do you mean by gap? The space between ```< 1999```  did not think that mattered if so.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. However even when I have <=1999 it gives the same issue. Or if I say >=2000.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am fairly new to all of this. Both your answer and Dan's answer helped me through this. It now works as it should. However I do have a question about one of the issues you said I might have, which is Problem 2. Are you saying I do not need Console.CursorLeft and only the Console.CursorTop -1?

Comment: I have gone through and made all the edits to this that caused the errors you pointed out.  It should now run. Thank you again.